# Use of punctuation of "First,...."

Tags: punctuation, commas, non-native-english

I am uncertain if and how to punctuate if I use only one sentence for the following idea:

> We conducted two varieties of an experiment. First, we left used method A. Second, we used method B.

Can I write this in the following way.

> We conducted the experiment, first with method A and second with method B.

Or should it be like this (which seems strange to me)

> We conducted the experiment, first, with method A, and second, with method B.

Comment: What does "First, we **left** used method A" mean?  Or is this a typo?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to include "first" and "second" at all? It doesn't seem to add much to your sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you can avoid commas by re-arranging things.

> We first conducted the experiment with method A, and then with method B.

Comment: Why is is necessary to use "firstly"? *First* functions just fine as an adverb without the suffix.

Comment: @phoog ... Correct. I've edited to remove.

Answer (score 1):

The problem faced is the wordiness. "We conducted two varieties of experiments." The "A" and "B" are listed. Hence, listing them signifies two varieties were conducted.

Try this: We conducted the experiment with method A and method B.

Answer (score -2):

Whenever I use commas, I think of them as pauses in the sentence. However, I believe that the proper way to do this is:

> We conducted the experiment; first with method A, and second with method B.

Comment: The semicolon is incorrect because the part following it is not a complete sentence.

Comment: I agree with phoog, but you could use a colon or an em-dash.